# Remove bottom page number on chapters first page

Tags: memoir

Here is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir} %showtrims removed for final PDF
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings} % activate changes
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{\small VOILÀ, C'EST DIT !}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\small\leftmark}{\thepage}

\chapterstyle{dash}

% Start ---------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{A l'ombre des jeunes filles en fleurs}
page 1

\newpage
page 2

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to get rid of the bottom page numbers on the first page of each chapter. I read the documentation but I'm struggling to understand how Memoir's `pagestyle` works.

Comment: `\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}`. Same to do for the even foot since you are using option `openany`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `memoir` class uses the `chapter` page style for the chapter starting pages; normally this page style is the same as `plain`, but we can modify them independently of each other.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir} %showtrims removed for final PDF
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headings} % activate changes
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{\small VOILÀ, C'EST DIT !}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\small\leftmark}{\thepage}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{}{}

\chapterstyle{dash}

% Start ---------------------------
\begin{document}

\chapter{A l'ombre des jeunes filles en fleurs}
page 1

\chapter{Nouveau}
page 2

\end{document}
```

[image]